# Why do I go into PartialView after peres Enter key in the PartialView that is in Modal?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem and I do not know how to solve it.
Why do I go into the `PartialView` after pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the `PartialView` that is in `Modal`?
My code is like this:

1. Load `PartialView` in `Modal`:

```js
<script>
        $(".panel-body").on('click', '.btn-success', function () {
            var modal = document.getElementById('AddModal');
            $('.Addspan').load('/Users/Phases/PhaseAdd/');
            modal.style.display = "block";
            window.onclick = function (event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="AddModal" class="modal AddModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="well Addspan">

        </div>

    </div><!-- Add modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

2. And `PartialView` in `Controller`:

   public ActionResult PhaseAdd()
       {
           ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "Name");
           return PartialView();
       }
3. `Partialview` code:

```html
@using Labkhand.Models
@model Labkhand.Models.Phase

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @{
            //بدست آوردن نام شرکت
            LabkhandModel db = new LabkhandModel();
            string co = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Company.Name;
        }
        <h4>افزودن عنوان شغلی برای <strong class="text-danger">@co</strong></h4>

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

        <div class="row" id="EditPhasePanel">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control",
                   onkeypress = "return runScript(event)"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" value="ذخیره" class="btn btn-danger btn-outline btnAddPhase"/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary closesPassModal" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="closeModal();">بستن</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    //Close modal
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function closeModal() {
                    document.getElementById('AddModal').style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
}
```

4. `Modal` image:
   [image: Modal Image]
5. After pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:
   [image: After Press Enter key]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved.

```js
$(document).keypress(
    function(event){
     if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
 
});
```